# xUnit Invocation failed with mock behavior strict

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I m getting and error when i write test to my code with xUnit. In that test methot i m trying to workerExist (İf is there any user or not) but in the test when i create action result belong to metot i take Invocation failed with mock behavior strict error. I couldnt find the solution

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var workerExist = _user.GetUserById(UserDto.userID);

        if (workerExist == null)
            return NotFound();

        var worker = new Workers
        {
            username = userDto.Username
        };

        await _workers.EditWorker(worker);

        return Ok(worker);
    }


public async Task EditUser_Should_Call_GetUserById_And_Return_NotFound_If_Returns_Null()
    {
        UserControllerMock mock = UserControllerMock.Create();
        mock.UserService.Setup(service => service.GetUserById(It.IsAny<int>())).ReturnsAsync(() => null);

        IActionResult actionresult = await mock.EditUser(new UserDto());
        var notFoundResult = actionresult as NotFoundResult;

        Assert.NotNull(notFoundResult);
        mock.UserService.Verify(service => service.GetUserById(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

Comment: that error is usually associated with Moq and how you setup your mock. Also in the test you setup `UserService` but verify `WorkerService` which was not invoked in the method under test.

Comment: Show `UserControllerMock.Create()` definition

Comment: Ah normally it s userservice in code too. Something happened wrong when i paste my code. Thanks for tell it. I edit it